# how to set readonly property in zend form add element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Hi I am new in zend framework.
I want to set ready only property on input box in zend Form.
example as we do in html

```
<input type ="text" readonly="readonly" />
```

this is my zend code:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'name', array(
            'label'      => '',
            'required'   => true,
            'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
            'style'    => array('width:338px'),
             'autocomplete' => 'off',
            'decorators'=>Array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Errors',

           ),
```

help mee

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$this->addElement('text','text_field',array('attribs' => array('readonly' => 'true')));
```

Comment: does the same thing work for radio, in my code it seems like it doesnt

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
$this->getElement('text')->setAttrib('readonly', 'readonly');
```

Answer (score 3):

In ZF2 you can create a form by extending Zend\Form and then add form element in the constructor. there  you can set the attributes as follows.

```
use Zend\Form\Form;

class MyForm extends Form {
    public function __construct() {

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'name',
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'readonly' => TRUE,
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Name : '
            )
        ));
     }
}
```